# How to keep td style elements that a function is removing?

Tags: jquery

This code is part of a fixedtableheader program.  However, when you turn on a pager feature (adds some arrows at the bottom of the table so you can advance forward pages at a time), it loses the style information that was in my tables' td values.  I want to modify this code so that it gets the td elements first from the my tds and add them as well to the td it creates.  Can somebody help with this?

Here is the function causing the lose of td elements for the same of adding class="ui-widget-content".  By the way, when I do not use the pager option, my style information remains, so I am not even sure 100% this is the cause, but I would like to try adding the elements back here if you can provide input on how to do tihs to see if that works.

```
    function objectToTable(objectArray,table){
        var body=$('tbody',table);
        body.children().remove();
        for(var i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++){
             tr=$('<tr></tr>');
             for(var j in objectArray[i]){
                  tr.append($('<td class="ui-widget-content"></td>').html(objectArray[i][j]));
             }
             body.append(tr);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure there's no other classes on the td's that need to be added to the new td's ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your web page simply adding the class in there with jQuery should do it.

```
$('td').addClass("ui-widget-content");
```

I suggest you modify the selector though for just the td elements instead of all of them on the page which this will do.

Comment: The fixheadertable found at http://www.tablefixedheader.com takes my <table><tr><td style="background-color:green">stuff</td> and is replacing it with <td class="ui-widget-content">stuff</td>, which then lets the rows appear with stuff, but I am losing my style="background-color:green" or whatever other color it has in a cell, which is not what I want.    Does using your suggestion somehow help keep the style= stuff?  How do you plug your suggestion into the code I supplied?

Comment: Then this is simple.  You should actually fix the ui-widget-content class for your color but you can use $('.ui-widget-content').css('background-color','green') to simply replace it.  Personaly i'd just find the css and change it there.

Comment: Note that I simply removed the whole function's process of removing the body and adding tr with new td class and added your addClass line.  This brought up the rows with the color style back , but the pager does not work. I thik the .html(objetArray[i][j] thing it is adding as well puts something to index the tr/td, which allows it to page down and up. I am not sure what .html thing is.  Is there a way to add that as well  I guess in the loop and keep to the spirit of not deleting all the children and readding back the rows with the class?

Comment: I wasnt suggesting you removed the existing code rather "add" this after the function runs or as the last line of the existing function.

Comment: Great info, but the next thing I would need if I do the .css("background-lcor',color" thing to tack on a color, how do I get the color from the original td style= line?

Comment: The color is getting created dynamically, so each cell will have a different color, which is why I cannot easily do this by modifying  a css.  If there is a way to extract the style color and then use the .css to add the color to each individual td during its for loop that would be great.

Comment: I tried: tr.append($('<td class="ui-widget-content"></td>').css('background-color','green').html(objectArray[i][j])); in the for loop, and that does change all cells to green.  The trick is I need to know the style color and somehow use that color.  Note that the td value if 0 is green, 1 is yellow, and higher is red.  Maybe we can do it that way?

Comment: I was able to use if (objectArray[i][j] == 0)  then do green, etc.  Is there a way to get the title= value into an array before they do the body.children().remove()?